# Prove that $\sqrt[3]{\sec\frac{2\pi }{7}} + \sqrt[3]{\sec\frac{4\pi }{7}} + \sqrt[3]{\sec\frac{8\pi }{7}} = \sqrt[3]{8-6\sqrt[3]{7}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:

$$\sqrt[3]{\sec\frac{2\pi }{7}} + \sqrt[3]{\sec\frac{4\pi }{7}} + \sqrt[3]{\sec\frac{8\pi }{7}} = \sqrt[3]{8-6\sqrt[3]{7}}$$

Thank you!

Avdiu...

Comment: I remember a problem of the German Mathematical Olympiad that could be related. The problem asked for a proof of this: if $a$ is the side of a regular heptagon, and $b$ and $c$ the lengths of the diagonals, then $1/a=1/b+1/c$. I've tried to solve this problem; I didn't get it, but I ended with cosines of $k\pi/7$ angles and a cubic equation.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\sec\frac{2\pi}{7},\qquad
\sec\frac{4\pi}{7},\qquad
\sec\frac{8\pi}{7}
$$
are the three zeros of the polynomial $z^3+4z^2-4z-8$ .

The cube-roots of those zeros are the zeros of the polynomial $y^9+4y^6-4y^3-8$ .  Using as a hint the right-hand side above, we can factor this polynomial to get a polynomial of degree 6 with no real roots, and a polynomial of degree 3 with three real roots
$$
y^3+(6\cdot 7^{1/3} - 8)^{1/3}y^2+\left(
\frac{(6\cdot 7^{1/3}-8)^{2/3}(3-4\cdot 7^{1/3}-3\cdot 7^{2/3})}{25}
\right)y-2
$$
and therefore the sum of its zeros is, indeed,
$$
-(6\cdot 7^{1/3}-8)^{1/3}
$$

Comment: How did you deduce that they are the roots of the cubic equation, $z^3+4z^2-4z-8=0$ ?